# How can i call the whole html page to a request handler JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html page with a simple form with a post method and a text area  field.
I want to call the whole of this html page to with a local variable and use http write method to return it to the browser.
This is the code snippet of the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="upload-htm" lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload file</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post">
      <textarea name="inpt-text" id="in-txt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">upload file</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="./requestHandlers.js"></script>

</html>
```

Then i also have a requestHandler.js file. My request handler should display the response it gets to the browser.

```
function start(res) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called");
  let body = document.getElementById('upload-htm');
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "content-type": "text/plain"
  });
  res.write(body);
  res.end();
}

function upload(res) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called");
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "content-type": "text/plain"
  });
  res.write(`Hello upload Mr. Paullaster`);
  res.end();
}
export {
  start,
  upload
};
```

When i run the code i get the following error from request handler start

```
PS C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive node> node -r esm 
index.js
Response ready
Request for /upload recieved
About to route a request for /upload 
Request handler 'upload' was called  
Request for /start recieved
About to route a request for /start 
Request handler 'start' was called  
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.start (C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive 
node\requestHandlers.js:5:15)
at route (C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive 
node\router.js:4:28)
at Server.onRequest (C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive 
node\server.js:11:8)
at Server.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:781:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
PS C:\Users\paullaster-geek\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Dive node>
```

Comment: Where  do you call these functions?

Comment: which functions.? I have an index.js file which the entry point to my application. import all my modules there. This error is so specific to the  'start' handler because even the 'upload handler just work very fine.

Answer (score 0):

A website usually consists of two major portions, the server side logic (back-end) and the client side logic (front-end). Both logics usually execute separately from each other, and therefore can only communicate via network channels, and not via logic. This means they do not share variables or data as conventional program logic does.

From the code you have shared, it appears that you are attempting to execute client side logic on your server side application. The `document` object in JavaScript is used to access and manipulate the DOM within an HTML page. The server side application does not have access to this `document` object, and therefore its access is invalid. In the server side application's context, document object is undefined.

You can make this work by calling these functions via client side logic. Try registering a function call for upload and start functions against a button click. That will most likely work.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS has a module called files system module. file system module has different methods that can be used to server nodejs static pages. it has:

```
           const readStream = createReadStream('./staticfile/index.html');
           res.writeHeader(200, {"content-type"}:"text/html");
           readStream.pipe(res)
```

this sends the html file in chucks of data.

refer here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html